# select 2 add additional parameters to select options

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I need additional parameters for `<option></option>` tag that generates by select2 from ajax data.

My ajax params for select2(coffee):

```
ajax:
  url: '/moysklad_warehouse_items/find_warehouse_item'
  dataType: 'json'
  delay: 500
  data: (query) ->
    { q: query.term }
  processResults: (data) ->
    { results: data }
```

Resulted data structure:

```
[{id: 1, text: 'one', price: 100, weight: 10},
 {id: w, text: 'two', price: 200, weight: 12}]
```

By default select2 provide only `id` and `text` parameters and select looks like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="10" selected="selected">one</option>
  <option value="11" selected="selected">one</option>
</select>
```

I want to add additional data(price and weight), like, that parameters take part in calculations and only `text` tag if insufficiently

```
<option value="11" selected="selected" price="12" weight="100">one</option>
```

If its impossible for `<option></option>` tag, it would be normal if I put, for example, `<span></span>` inside `<option>` and add parameters to `<span>`

Comment: Read about `data-*` attributes..

Answer (score 1):

I can get access for my additional parameters by `$('select').select2('data')` and get object with all parameters

Answer (score 0):

If JQuery is an option :

```
 $('#optionTag').attr('my-awesome-attr','12'); //this is if you give the option tag an idea of 'optionTag'
```

Comment: I've never used Select2 or CoffeeScript im afraid :(